How to do a gaussian blur without modifying the original pixels?
Given an image such as below, I want to blur it such that none of the original black pixels change in value. The blur should have a nice S curve fade-off to white.

If I apply a 15px gaussian blur to this image I get this:

It fades out nicely, but if I put a red square where the original black square was, you can see that actually the blur has exposed some parts of it:

Now I recently found out that a 15px gaussian blur means 1 std deviation is 15px, the actual full radius of affected pixels is closer to ¾√2π*σ. Technically infinite, but most programs limit it to that, from what I hear. So for a 15px blur, if I expand my box by 29px then gaussian blur by 15px, the extend of the blur ought to just barely reach back to my original box, leaving it undisturbed, right?

That looks pretty good, but if I put my red box back again we can see that there is still a difference:

The red doesn't show through (much), but I can still see a hard outline.

Is there a better suited blur algorithm for this than gaussian? What I'm imagining is something like we find the normals for the edges of the box/shape and then draw an S curve along that normal. This would probably be easier if I had a vector image, but I have bitmaps, so I don't know what the closest equivalent would be.

Blur a copy of the image and then composite the original and the blurred copy choosing the darker (or minimum) of the two at each location.

@MarkSetchell I think that's essentially the same as the final image I showed. It's close, but I can still see a hard outline of original image. It should have a nice S-curve falloff where I can't quite make out the original edge.

what is all this for? is this just for an artistic "shadow" effect?

No, that cannot be. If you select the darker pixel between the original black and the blurred black, your original black pixels will always cover everything (red) that they ever covered.

on this suggestion in the comments, I agree with mpen.

I am confused as to what you are really asking. Is it 1) how to avoid any of the originally black pixels changing colour as a result of the blur, or 2) how to control the shape/roll-off of the blur outside the originally black pixels?

@MarkSetchell If I put pure black where the red is, then yes, none of the red would show through. The point is that the blur is cutting into the original square which indicates that its not a nice smooth falloff starting at the edges of the square. (1) Is trivial on its own, (2) Is the tricky part to get just right.

@ChristophRackwitz I want to use it as a mask for some images to blend them together. If the original mask isn't pure black, the other image will show through. But I want nice soft edges so they blend nicely together, so you can't see the seams.

yeah go with the distance thingy. signed distance fields would be even fancier. do a distance transform for each shape. then you can decide how to handle "overlap".

The problem is that design of  Gaussian blur  is isotropic, meaning it diffuses the intensity of each pixel equally in all directions.
You should try generating a binary mask of the black region, computing its distance transform, and than applying a scaling curve (exponential decay) to map the distance values to intensity values.
If I understood correctly what you are trying to achieve, reading this might help you with the realization.

Thanks! I was able to come up with this using your suggestion

This is the right solution. OP wants an s-shaped curve, I would use a cubic polynomial to scale the distances, since most s-shapes curves (error function, sigmoid) have an infinite extent and will not reach 1 on the boundary of the object.

The distance transform produces a bit of a funny effect when you have 2 pieces of mask close together. It would be better if they just blurred together, rather than creating these lines. Looks look a voronoi diagram.

The problem is that a Gaussian never becomes zero. Just very close to it.
No matter of how much dilation (shifting) you apply, it'll never stop.
The only thing making a Gaussian "stop" is quantization, e.g. having values 0 to 255 instead of "actual" real numbers.
You could pick something other than a Gaussian. Anything with a finite support region would do. "Good" old box blur is such a thing. Repeated application of a box blur approaches a Gaussian, yet stays finite in the strict mathematical sense.
If you're going the path of a distance transform and apply a curve to the distance to get your "fading out", the input data will have to be binary/binarized. On a distance transform, you can apply any function you can think of. Even the positive half of a Gaussian, because the distance is a scalar, not an image.
That "S-curve" you speak of sounds somewhat like a "Raised cosine".

I don't love that the distance transform requires the input to be binarized, but I could probably live with that if it didn't also have have this issue where if the 'radius' touches another part of the mask it produces a voronoi-like effect. I'll try a box blur; didn't think of that. "Raised cosine" sounds about right, in the pic only β=1 has the nice gradual falloff though. I'd want to play with the steepness in the middle part, but it should have no 'ceil' like the other βs.

Given the original image:

I came up with this:

It's a bit easier to see when colorized:

The red is the original mask, the blue is the blur. The blue fade should begin where the red edge stops.
Applying a simple convolution to the whole image causes the 'fade' to cut into the original mask, so to fix this I expanded/dilated the mask by taking the max value over the same radius as the kernel. This is built into torch as max_pool2d.
Here's the full code (in Python):
def run(self, *, mask: torch.Tensor, radius: int):
    assert mask.ndim == 3, "Expected mask to have shape [B,H,W]"
    assert radius > 0, "Radius must be positive"

    # Define kernel size (2 * radius + 1 to cover the full area)
    kernel_size = 2 * radius + 1

    # Create a round Gaussian kernel
    y, x = torch.meshgrid(
        torch.arange(-radius, radius + 1, device=mask.device),
        torch.arange(-radius, radius + 1, device=mask.device),
        indexing="ij"
    )
    distance = torch.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)
    gaussian_kernel = torch.exp(-0.5 * (distance / radius) ** 2)
    gaussian_kernel /= gaussian_kernel.sum()
    gaussian_kernel = gaussian_kernel.view(1, 1, kernel_size, kernel_size)

    # Expand the mask by replicating the edges before applying max_pool2d
    padded_mask = F.pad(mask, (radius, radius, radius, radius), mode="replicate")

    # Apply max pooling to simulate dilation
    dilated_mask = F.max_pool2d(padded_mask.unsqueeze(1), kernel_size, stride=1, padding=radius, ceil_mode=True)

    # Apply Gaussian blur to the dilated mask
    blurred_mask = F.conv2d(dilated_mask, gaussian_kernel, padding=0)  # Implicitly crops back to original size

    # Remove the channel dimension
    blurred_mask = blurred_mask.squeeze(1)

    # Shouldn't be necessary...
    # final = torch.clamp(torch.maximum(blurred_mask, mask), 0, 1)

    return self.output({"blurred_mask": blurred_mask})

The only thing I don't love is that the circles get squared off a bit, but it's not too bad.

I did not suggest anything that would cause "the 'fade' to cut into the original mask". I explained that's what happened.

@ChristophRackwitz I was referring to "box blur". I didn't mean any offense, was just trying to give you credit for the suggestion because it was a good one. I've removed it.
